# Creating editable PDF using FO

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf

I need to convert an XML file containing data into a PDF with some editable fields, like comment boxes and digital signatures.
For now, I am using XSLT based FO to take XML file as input and convert it into PDF file without any editable components.

Is it possible to use FO to add editable objects as well? If yes, how?
If no, is there a way to migrate FO based development to any other tool? (for e.g. have heard iText as an alternate solution).

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Regards,
Saumya Govil

Answer (score 0):

RenderX (commercial product) supports Acroform fields through XSL FO extension elements. You can use XSL FO and insert fillable form fields in the document

http://www.renderx.com/reference.html#PDF%20Forms

Here's a sample of what you can create with XSL FO and the extensions for PDF Forms:

http://public.tandesa.com/Xportability/Services/PDFForms/pdfforms.pdf

(Be sure to not use a javascript viewer that does not support forms to view that link, you should use Adobe Reader or something that supports forms).

Comment: Dear Kevin, Thanks for your reply. I checked and find RenderX good. I wanted to try the PDF form feature but could not make it work in the  trial version. Do you know if we can test it only in the licensed version or am I doing somethig wrong that it doesn't work for me?